# Undo git rm filename?

Tags: git

I did a `git rm somefile` and I wish to just undo it.  Is there a way to do that?

In other words I just want to restore that one file and everything else should stay the same.

Comment: Note that if you type `git status` with no switches, it will show a message telling you exactly how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this, If you have not committed yet.

```
git checkout somefile
```

If you have already committed, then you can only get the file from previous commit. That can be done by:

```
git checkout HEAD~ somefile
```

Answer (score 0):

git checkout HEAD path/to/file